# jsoup - parsing the first row of a table doesn't work

Tags: java, android, parsing, jsoup

I really tried a lot and also searched a lot of websites...
I tried to parse a price from a website with jsoup, but it didn't work.

What I tried out is this:

```
    try {
                String str1 = "https://www.google.de/shopping/product/3996339592576509511?hl=de&q=4250155834791&oq=4250155834791&gs_l=products-cc.3...4306.7625.0.8037.13.6.0.7.0.0.60.314.6.6.0...0.0...1ac.1.LgJKDfZQvls&sa=X&ei=eeqlUY2zFNT54QSyloCoDw&ved=0CFIQgggwAA&prds=scoring:p";
                doc = Jsoup.connect(str3).get();
                final Elements elements = doc.select("td:lt(1)");

                String price = doc.select("span").first().text();

                System.out.println(price);
                System.out.println("Ende");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The goal should be to extract the lowest price of the product.
example-page:

https://www.google.de/shopping/product/3996339592576509511?hl=de&q=4250155834791&oq=4250155834791&gs_l=products-cc.3...4306.7625.0.8037.13.6.0.7.0.0.60.314.6.6.0...0.0...1ac.1.LgJKDfZQvls&sa=X&ei=eeqlUY2zFNT54QSyloCoDw&ved=0CFIQgggwAA&prds=scoring:p

I would like to parse the first row that shows me the results.
in this case: ebay 24-trade365.

I need the article's price and the link to the vendor.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1):

You'd do better extracting by class, also when you select for "span" you are selecting in the original doc, not the elements you have extracted. Try something like:

```
// get all column entries for price
final Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("os-price-col");    
int lowest_price = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
// foreach entry
for(Element element : elements){
    // get the price in text form
    String text_price = element.text();
    // convert to an integer
    text_price = text_price.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");
    int price = Integer.parseInt(text_price);
    // check if it's the lowest
    if(price < lowest_price) lowest_price = price;
}
System.out.println(lowest_price);
```

Obviously updating slightly to get the output in a format you want.

EDIT: Just saw that you wanted the vendor link as well. In this case I would extract a row at a time i.e.

```
Elements rows = doc.getElementsByClass("os-row");
```

Then iterate through each row and pick out the price as before, but this time do

```
row.getElementsByClass("os-price-col").first();
```

And if it's the lowest you can pick out the vendor url with something like

```
row.getElementsByClass("os-seller-name").first().select("a").attr("href");
```

Comment: When I use your snippet, I geht 2147483647 (max. value of INT).

Comment: So, it read out nothing. Don't get it working, can you help some more, please?

Comment: Try checking that elements is non-empty and add a print statement to check what element.text() is - perhaps I chose the wrong class names when inspecting the html.

Answer (score 1):

If your table is already sorted and all you want is the first row:

```
Element table=doc.getElementsByClass("os-main-table").first();
Element firstRow=table.select("tr[class=os-row").first();
Element seller=firstRow.select("td[class=os-seller-name]").first();
String sellerName=seller.text().trim();
String sellerLink=seller.getElementsByTag("a").first().attr("href");        
String price=firstRow.select("td[class=os-price-col").first().getElementsByClass("os-base_price").text();
```

You can find a tutorial on Jsoup navigation at http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation